# How to add transparency to only a part of a mesh

Tags: mesh, transparency

I want to add transparency to only a part of a mesh and not the whole object.
For example making pants' pocket area slightly transparent so what's inside the pocket can be seen. The image is what I'm trying to make it similar to.
How can this be achieved?[image]

Answer (score 0):

idk if this is exactly what you're looking for but if you're using the **principled BSDF**, you're first going to want to adjust the *alpha slider* of the pocket's material.

[image]

Then you're going to change the **blend mode** to *alpha blend* and for the shadow to something like *alpha hash*. Then you should get some sort of translucent material.

[image]

Comment: I think this is a little different to what I'm having to do. Since I don't want the whole pocket material to be half invisible, I need to find a way to select only a part of the pocket material and make it invisible. Anther method I tried was using weight paint and mask modifier but it makes it completely invisible. I have added an image as an example.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an image with black and grey and use it as a mask between your basic texture (here a *Principled BSDF*) and transparency. In Eevee don't forget to choose *Material > Settings > Blend Mode > Alpha Blend*:

[image]

Comment: Could you help me a little more with your method? adding that image to my own mesh didn't seem to make any difference. I also added an image on my post as an example.

Comment: please pack your image (File > External Data > Pack Resources), save and share your file, use https://blend-exchange.com/ or another platform like workupload

Comment: Using the image as a mix factor and a fully _Transparent BSDF_ (fully white color) as the transparency makes the _Transparent BSDF_ act like an alpha channel - so this setup is redundant as you can simply plug the image into the _Alpha_ input of the _Principled BSDF_.

Comment: It is not redundant as I didn't plug it into the Alpha but yes it's the same as plugging it into the Alpha

Comment: @moonboots Haha, you're right... no native speaker, struggling to find the correct words... redundant in the sense of, you create an artificial alpha channel although there is already one 